# Convergence of power series at the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

Consider the following complex power series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{ni^n}{2^n}{z^{n-1}}}
$$
By the root test, I have concluded that the disc of convergence is $D:=D(0,2)$. Then, I would like to study the convergence of the series in $\partial D$. Considering $z=2e^{i\theta}\in \partial D$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the series becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}{n i^n e^{i(n-1)\theta}}
$$
which is not absolutely convergent and, indeed,
$$
\lim_{n} n i^n e^{i(n-1)\theta} \neq 0
$$
for every $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, so the series cannot be convergent at the boundary. Is this reasoning true, or am I missing some aspect of the boundary convergence of complex power series? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: It is correct. $\sum z_n$ cannot converge if $z_n$ does not tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.
To be more precise: let $a_n:=n i^n e^{i(n-1)\theta}$, then $|a_n|=n$ for all $n$, thus $(a_n)$ does not converge to $0.$